# 401 unauthorized using google task

Tags: c#, oauth, httpwebrequest, google-api

I'm learning to use google task api rest.

i have succeed getting access tokken.

now i am trying to get tasklist using this rest url: https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists

In google task documentation write that i need to sent Access tokens by HTTP Authorization header but i don't know how
[link](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html#basicsteps)

i have search for result in the web but didn't found a solution.
I have also searched this site for solution, but didn't get one.

i am getting 401 unauthorized error in when trying to request.GetResponse();
this is my code

```
 private AccessToken _accessToken = null;
private string Apikey = "my api key";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _accessToken = (AccessToken)Session["AccessTokken"];
    string _customerkey = "my customer key";
    string _customerSecret = "my customer secret key";
    Response.Write(_accessToken.Token);

    string nostring = "";
    string nnString = "";
    OAuthBase oauth = new OAuthBase();
    Uri t = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists");
    string u = oauth.GenerateSignature(t, _customerkey, _customerSecret, _accessToken.Token,
                                       _accessToken.TokenSecret, "GET", oauth.GenerateTimeStamp(),
                                       oauth.GenerateNonce(), out nostring, out nnString);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(nostring);
    request.Method = "GET";

    //request.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + _accessToken.Token);
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();


    Response.Write(responseString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Google publishes a [.Net library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) for accessing Google Api, this includes helpers for doing the authentication I would suggest using this Api and starting from the [samples](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Downloads?tm=2) the project publishers (including [Task Api Sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg/Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2)).

If you want to carry on hand cranking the Api call you can either just use the [communications library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=contrib#hg/Current/Generated/Lib), or look at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=default#hg/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/Authentication) and see how Google has done the communication.

## EDIT

From the source linked above you can find the [OAuth Authenticator](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/Authentication/OAuth3LeggedAuthenticator.cs#73) which adds http header [System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httprequestheader.aspx) with the value specified in [OAuthUtil.GenerateHeader](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/Oauthutil.cs?r=5b63689fcb1ec74a145f2d03b2ad103aa1526afc#68). The relevant section copied below.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Authorization: OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\",");
sb.AppendFormat("oauth_nonce=\"{0}\",", EncodingPerRFC3986(nonce));
sb.AppendFormat("oauth_timestamp=\"{0}\",", EncodingPerRFC3986(timeStamp));
sb.AppendFormat("oauth_consumer_key=\"{0}\",", EncodingPerRFC3986(consumerKey));
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
{
    sb.AppendFormat("oauth_token=\"{0}\",", EncodingPerRFC3986(
}
sb.Append("oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",");
sb.AppendFormat("oauth_signature=\"{0}\"", EncodingPerRFC3986(signature));

return sb.ToString();
```

You can use just this bottom layer of the Api and not worry about the generated services. Remember this code is covered by http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 so it may be easier in a legal seance to use the DLL for this specific function rather then coping it directly.

Comment: I'm familiar with .NET library for Google API, but i want to use httpRequest. because it would be good for twitter api also, ans anthers rest api.
all i need is to know the syntax that would sent the access tokken to google.